# How to edit For loop to include row summation of multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm learning arrays (new to C++ to say the least) and am trying to do the following:

1. create a 12x12 array of random numbers (with a given seed)
2. sum the elements of each column
3. sum the elements of each row
4. display a 13x13 matrix including the random numbers and the sum of the rows (step 3) and columns (step 2)

My code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int M = 12;
const int N = 12;

int myArray[M + 1][N] = { 0 };

void generateArray();
void sumRowsAndColumns();
void printSumRowsAndColumns();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    generateArray();
    sumRowsAndColumns();

    return 0;
}

void generateArray()
{
    // set the seed
    unsigned setSeed = 1023;

    srand(setSeed);

    // generate the matrix using pseudo-random numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j] = rand() % 100;

            // outputs the raw matrix (in case we need to see it)
            //          cout << left << setw(4) << myArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        //      cout << endl;
    }
    //  cout << endl << endl;
}

void sumRowsAndColumns()
{
    cout << endl;

    // for the columns
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
            myArray[M][j] += myArray[i][j];
    }
    printSumRowsAndColumns();
}

void printSumRowsAndColumns()
{

    // for the columns
    for (int i = 0; i < M + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << left << setw(6) << myArray[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm able to do all but # 3 above.  I've tried (very unsuccessfully!) to include some for loops to treat the sum of the row elements, but can't seem to get it to run (and, at times, have caused infinite loops).  Would anyone be able to give me some guidance on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.
Ryan

P.S. I know that vectors are the way to go here, but technically we have not learned about them yet, so the expectation is that we use arrays.

*** UPDATE ***

I've tweaked the sumRowsAndColumns() function based on the suggestions below and I'm seeing expected results for the column sum.  But, I'm seeing an error when I try to sum up the columns.  The new code is:

```
void sumRowsAndColumns()
{
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            rowSum[i] += myArray[i][j];
            colSum[j] += myArray[i][j];
        }
        cout << left << setw(6) << rowSum[i] << endl;
//      cout << left << setw(6) << colSum[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

The line that's commented out:

```
//      cout << left << setw(6) << colSum[j] << endl;
```

is causing an error ("j": undeclared identifier).  I'm identifying 'j' the same as 'i'.  Do I have this line of code in the wrong place in the for loop?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your array is a `13x12`....Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: are you saying you are not able to calculate sum of all elements in a row for each row ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you've made a 13x12 array.  If you want to store the row sums and column sums in the same array, you'd need a 13x13.  I'd suggest you make it a 12x12 and make two 12x1 arrays to hold the sums.

int col_sum[M], row_sum[M];

and initialize them to zero.

Then your loop looks something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
         row_sum[i] += myArray[i][j];
         col_sum[j] += myArray[i][j];
        }
}
```

If it has to be all in one array, you should be able to work it out as a 13x13.  The row_sum array is the 13th column and the col_sum is the 13th row.  I personally don't think it's a good idea to mix data in an array like that - the 12x12 is for the random data, the 12x1 arrays are for the results.

If you get stuck, just sketch it out on a piece of paper with a smaller array and use that to understand how the loops walk through the array.